# Angular ngview + hash

Tags: angularjs

Imagine you have table data on the left and charts on the right. The table data is angular and charts are shown in D3 wrapped in a directive. The whole page itself is an angular view. I click on a particular svg element in the chart, I want to scroll to and highlight the corresponding row in the table.

On the controller side, when the click event happens, I use this code:

```
$scope.onChartClick = function (chartNode) {
              $location.hash(chartNode.RowID);
              $anchorScroll();
      }
```

The problem I have is anchrollScroll forces reload of DOM. Is there anyway I could ignore the route when it contains the hash ? So that I can use the existing DOM but just to scroll to the particular TR.

Is there a better way ? I just want to scroll to the TR when the corresponding bar is clicked in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first add :

```
...config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

..so that you don't have anymore the # symbol in the URL's, and also did you try to use event.preventDefault(); to remove the default behavior of the links and stop the refresh of the pages?